# Solutions of ODE from Mathematica and Laplace transform differ

Tags: differential-equations, integral-transforms

The equation is 
$p'(t)=k_1s_0{e}^{-k_1t}-k_2p(t)$

The solution with  Mathematica

```
DSolve[p'[t] == k1*s0*E^(-k1*t) - k2*p[t], p[t], t]
```

$p(t) =  -(k_1/(k_1-k_2)) s_0 (e^{-k_1t}) 
+ p(0) e^{-k_2t}$

but when I applied Laplace transform the result is

$p(t) =  (k_1/(k_1-k_2)) s_0 (e^{-k_1t}–e ^{-k_2t}) 
+ p(0) e^{-k_2t}$

I followed this Laplace transform mentioned in the appendix from this paper:
[enter link description here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8693/d7b4c3275236bc8315aeaf8f8798035a46fc.pdf?_ga=2.73298323.1494748044.1564077606-1482887589.1564077606)

I am wondering where is the mistake.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please, always post the code that produced the results (please, in _copyable_ form). Otherwise, we cannot tell what went wrong.

Comment: The code from Mathematica is

DSolve[p'[t] == k1*s0*E^(-k1*t) - k2*p[t], p[t], t]

I am wondering could that solution be wrong?

Comment: Please post the original code in correct [markdown](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (not in $\LaTeX$!) and put that into your original post. Moreover, the code for the result from the Laplace transform is still missing.

Answer (score 2):

Possible typo/initial value not given in `DSolve`? (note the $c_1$ returned by DSolve may not necessarily be p[0]). The two agree for me:

```
eqn = p'[t] == k1*s0*E^(-k1*t) - k2*p[t]
dsol = DSolve[{eqn, p[0] == p0}, p[t], t]
leqn = ApplySides[LaplaceTransform[#, t, s] &, eqn]
lsol = Solve[leqn, LaplaceTransform[p[t], t, s]]
ilsol = InverseLaplaceTransform[
   LaplaceTransform[p[t], t, s] /. lsol[[1]], s, t] // FullSimplify
s1 = p[t] /. {dsol[[1, 1]]} /. {p0 -> p[0]}
s1 == ilsol // FullSimplify
```

Returns `True`

Comment: I expected something the like. Good job! (+1)

Comment: So @egwene sedai do you mean that the second solution is correct? And why simple DSolve doesn't solve the equation? Thanks.

Comment: @Ксения Цочева Your call of `DSolve` _did_ solve the ODE, but the general one with one integration constant that does not coincide with $p(0)$. Note that the ODE has _infinitely many_ solutions when you do not specify its initial condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood the problem.